# Avoid IF statements in a Fortran DO loops

Tags: if-statement, fortran, gfortran, do-loops

In my Fortran program I have something similar to this do loop

```
do i = 1,imax
    if(period) then
        call g_period()
    else
        call g()
    endif
 enddo
```

I have this several places and sometimes several If loops within a do loop which checks whether I should call function X or Y. What is common for all this is that period is defined in the input file, and it is unchanged during the whole run time. 
Is there a way to avoid the if statements - because my speed is killed by all the checking stuff? Although, I want to maintain the generic why of being able to run the program one time with period = true and other times with period=false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the speed is really crucial you can always write two different versions. One for true and one for false:

```
if(period) then
  do i = 1,imax
    call g_period()
  end do
else
  do i = 1,imax
    call g()
  end do
end if
```

You can have even completely separate subroutine and everything.

When you call subroutines, `g()` and the alternative, that do serious work, it is likely that there won't be too much performance penalty for the if. However, if you do stuff like looping over a large 3D array of many points and do some mathematical operation in every point, with just a few exeptions, it may even be faster to to compute it everywhere and undo it for those few exceptional points afterwards, rather than introduce a brench into the tight loop.

Comment: This is not ideal if my do loop is much bigger than this example.

Comment: Well, there are always trade-offs. Faster code is often not as nice and short. You can sometimes generate the subroutines or loops from a common include file.

Comment: @AliT. if the loop is so big then the overhead of the `if` call is likely not consequential.

Comment: That is true. One should always profile if the if is really slowing it. I have certainly met cases where that was the case.

Comment: To be fair, if there are subroutine calls involved, there the likelihood of the if being important to performance is pretty low.